# where can i get Android Huawei Y511-t00 driver?

Tags: android

Now I have a Android Phone.It is Huawei Y511-t00.
by the way, My computer does not recognize my phone.
So, I installed HUAWEIinSuite. but I can not...
I can not emulator in real device because avd can not recognize my phone.
I can use my phone via usb memory.
but avd...

Please help me

Comment: A few corrections, since it's easier to find useful information if you use the correct terms: the Android emulator is something you'd typically run on a computer. When you're running you app on a real device you're not emulating it. Also, an _AVD_ is a virtual device that you use with the Android emulator. Perhaps you meant _ADB_ (the Android Debug Bridge).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://androidxda.com/download-huawei-usb-drivers.

Google might also help you the next time.

Please also take a look at the help center.
Stackoverflow might not be the right place for a Driver/USB-Problem